# How to compile the C file that uses LLVM on Windows

Tags: llvm

I have installed LLVM by LLVM-16.0.0-win64.exe on windows. But it doesn't include llvm-config tool. What is the command line to compile my c file that include like #include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"? In other words, how to specify the lib path which contains LLVMContext.h?

how to use LLVM without llvm-config?

Comment: What compiler and environment (IDE/editor/makefile/etc.) are you using?

Comment: Thank you. I am using MinGW on windows. I just use vs code to edit and compile on PowerShell manually without any makefile.

Comment: When you're building you need to use the `-I` (upper-case i) option to tell the compiler where to find header files. Then you need to use the `-l` (lower-case L) option to tell the linker to link with specific libraries.

Comment: Actrually, I cannot find the lib path or header files for #include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h" in installation folder on Windows.

Comment: Do a search for `LLVMContext.h` on your full drive.

Comment: Thanks. Just find LLVMContext.h is referenced by "C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\LLVM-C.lib".  I thought it should be in folder "C:\Program Files\LLVM\include".

Comment: It is said that the pre-built LLVM installer for Windows only contains the toolchain parts: clang, lld, compiler-rt libraries, etc.  The best way is to build LLVM libraries yourself if need them.